# Show that the inequality $\frac{s}{t} + \frac{t}{r} + \frac{r}{s} >= 3$, assuming s,t,r >0.

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For this question, I made an assumption that $r<=s<=t$. If I manage to proof it under this assumption, is the result still hold true when $r<=t<=s$ or $ t<=s<=r$, if it is true, why?

Sorry, I didn't learn about AM-GM inequality. Would you mind to explain how AM-GM inequality works in this question here? My knowledge of AM-GM is limited to $a^2+b^2>=2ab $....

Thank you very much for your reply. This question has been confusing me for a long period of time.

Comment: Henry. Assuming s,t,r >0 ? AM-GM?

Comment: Yes, I think we are assuming s,t,r >0.

Comment: But then use $a+b+c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$

Comment: @Peter Szilas Thank you very much... But I don't know AM-GM's application in this way.. sorry. The way I did it is manipulating the variables

Comment: @Peter Szilas Would you mind to explain it in more detail? Thank you very much

Comment: Henry. For these problems AM-GM is handy.It is worth looking it up. For 2 variables $(a+b \ge 2√a√b) $ quite easy to prove. Look it up in Wiki, for example.

Comment: @Peter Szilas Thank you veery much, I finally got it. Using Jensen's inequalities to prove AM-GM; then, this works. Again, much thanks

Comment: Very good. AM-GM proof for 3 variables you also find at Stack exchange.Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{s}{t}-\frac{s}{r}\right)=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(s^2r-s^2t)}{str}=\frac{(s-t)(t-r)(r-s)}{str}\geq0$$ for $r\leq s\leq t$, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for $r\leq t\leq s$.

But it's better to use AM-GM: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{s}{t}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{s}{t}\cdot\frac{t}{r}\cdot\frac{r}{s}}=3.$$

I use AM-GM for three numbers:

> for positives $x$, $y$ and $z$ we have:
>   $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{xyz}$$

or $$x+y+z\geq3\sqrt[3]{xyz}.$$
Now, take $x=\frac{s}{t},$ $y=\frac{t}{r}$ and $z=\frac{r}{s}.$

Comment: Thank you very much... would you mind to explain  $\sum_{cyc}$ for me? I didn't learn that...

Comment: @Henry Cai $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{s}{t}=\frac{s}{t}+\frac{t}{r}+\frac{r}{s}.$

Comment: Thank you, but why $\sqrt[3]{\frac{s}{t} \cdot \frac{t}{r} \cdot \frac{r}{s}} >=1 $...

Comment: @Henry Cai Because $\frac{s}{t}\cdot\frac{t}{r}\cdot\frac{r}{s}=\frac{str}{trs}=1.$

Comment: Thank you very much... I still don't understand how does cyc works in AM-GM inequality. Sorry for any inconvenience I made. I will search on it .

Comment: I get it thank you

Comment: @Henry Cai  You are welcome!

Comment: I got the AM-GM part.. thank you. How does the cycling variables part work? Would you mind to eexplain more, I really need it.

Comment: @Henry Cai Just $s\rightarrow t\rightarrow r\rightarrow s$. For example, $\sum\limits_{cyc}s=s+t+r$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}st=st+tr+rs$. See also my previous example,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103056/discussion-between-henry-cai-and-michael-rozenberg).